# Converting Excel to Google Sheets and replacing

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to programming, learning on the fly.
I have a google account for work and use mainly google sheets.
I need to combine one google sheet with info I get from a file that I can only export in xlxs. I found a code [here](https://www.labnol.org/code/20500-convert-microsoft-excel-xlsx-to-google-spreadsheet) that converts excel to google sheets at the moment that I upload it to drive.

```
function convertExceltoGoogleSpreadsheet2(fileName) {  try {

fileName = fileName || "microsoft-excel.xlsx";

var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
var fileId = excelFile.getId();
var folderId = Drive.Files.get(fileId).parents[0].id;
var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
var resource = {
  title: excelFile.getName().replace(/\.xlsx?/, ""),
  key: fileId
};
Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {
  convert: true
});  } catch (f) {
Logger.log(f.toString());}}
```

So far so good.

The problem now is that every time I export the information and upload the xlxs to my drive, it generates a **new** google sheet file. I want it to **replace** it, because I need to reference this file in another one to create a new report.

Anyone know if this is possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the Excel file after creating the Google Sheet using this:

```
 DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).setTrashed(true);
```

Strictly speaking, there is no way to replace the Excel file with the Google Sheet. You can only create a Google Sheet version of the Excel file.

And you won't be able to link to cells or sheet of the Excel file from a Google Sheet (if that is what you meant by "reference").

Comment: Thank you! But not exactly what I need. Here are the steps I would need to follow:

1. Download Excel file
2. Upload it to Drive
3. Automatically convert it to Google Sheet A
4. In google sheet B, use information from google sheet A using importrange
5. Download updated excel file with same file name
6. Upload it to Drive to the same folder
7. Automatically convert to Google Sheet and replace google sheet A with the new version
8. My importrange from googlesheet B still works and now has updated info

Steps 1 through 4 work fine with the code I have. My problem starts in step 7.

Comment: Hello @cachi! I don't understand when you say that your current problem is to «*Automatically convert to Google Sheet and replace google sheet A with the new version*». As @ADW said, there is no direct way to accomplish that, but you can use the workaround of deleting the old file using the mentioned comment. Could you please explain to me what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hello @Jacques-GuzelHeron, thank you! What I mean is that when I upload the excel file, the code converts it to google sheet, but instead of replacing the previously existing google sheet with the same name, it creates a new one, with a new ID. What I need is to keep the same ID (replace the google sheet).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, I understand that you want to upload a Excel file in Drive, converting it into Sheet format, and using the same ID as an old Excel file already in drive (effectively replacing it).

If the above is correct, then I am afraid to inform you that it is not possible to do it. As you can read [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/manage-uploads#use_a_pregenerated_id_to_upload_files), this operation can't be completed if you are requesting to convert the file into a Google Document format (as you are doing uploading the Excel into Sheet).